# How to configure one Azure ADDS for all inherit Azure accounts under the same subscription?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

We have a **Visual Studio Enterprise Subscription – MPN** subscription. Therefore, we can **create several Azure accounts under the same subscription in the same tenet**. So, Basically we have an **one root Azure account and several Azure accounts which are inherited to the root Azure account In my environment**, I have configured **Azure ADDS under my root Azure account**. I have **several VMs in another Azure account under the same subscription** as I described above. **My requirement is to connect those Azure VMs to the Azure ADDS in the root Azure account. Is there any way to do it?** I know how to do it when Azure ADDS and Azure VMs in the same account.

Answer (score 0):

As you aware Azure Active Directory Domain services integrates with your existing Azure AD tenant. This integration lets users sign in to service and applications connected to the managed domain using their existing credentials. Joining the VM hosted in another Tenant is not applicable . You have mentioned different Azure Account if it is a different Tenant then there is no possibility at this time.

Comment: As i said, different Azure account but for the same tenet.